# Can i change 5 pins tact switch to 4 pins tact switch?

Tags: switches

I have AOC brand monitor with a manuall buttons which operate the menu OSD.
I would like to change the original tact switches(there are 5 tact switches) buttons in the circuit board.The problem is that the tact switches have 5 pins while i have only the 4 pins ones(6X6X5mm).
If i will solder the 4 pin switches instead of the original 5 pins tact switches ,will it affect the operation of the button?will it works?Does the fifth pin has important function that without it,it will not function properly,if at all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the switching contact configuration of both switches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often a 5-pin tactile switch can be replaced with a similar 4-pin (or fewer pin) tactile switch.

If you look at the PCB where the switch is mounted you may be able to determine which of the pins are important (input to output).  Often one or more PCB pins will contact the metal frame of the switch, this pin is not normally important except for some small bit of shielding or rigidity it might provide.  Also common is multiple contacts connected to the same side of the switch.

Looking at the PCB you might see that two pins on each side of the switch are shorted together, then two pins on the other side are also shorted together, (sometimes the extra pins will just go no where at all).  The replacement switch just needs to make contact from one side to the other (input to output). You might even be able to use a switch with only two pins as a replacement, (if you can verify the PCB connections).  Just be sure that the contact point is at the same location as the original.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqdtDl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So,the 4 pin tactile switch is exactly as the 5 pins tactile,except the latter has one more pin which doesn't related to any connection among the other pins or function as a pass of current flow in the circuit,but only  for rigidiy/shielding.Am i right?It doesn't function as a ground or something like that,does it?

Comment: Your explanation is "typical", though there are other more complex switches where the other pins might be more important or could be used as looped circuit connections.  Not knowing your exact switch type or the PCB design the word "typical" is the most appropriate response. As stated looking over the circuit connections of your PCB can give you more information about the importance of each pin.

Comment: Does the 5 pins tactile switch that work as osd manual buttons at most LCD computor monitors use only two pins as input and output,while the fifth one is usually only for rigidity?

Comment: I had been changed the tact switches and i can confirm that the fifth pin is used only to provide the tact switch more grip to the electric board and nothing more(there are no electric connections with the other pins).the tact switch  works exactly as shown at the photo that Nedd attached above on the left.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that it won't work without some little jumper wires.

All of the 5-lead tact switches that I have seen have 4 corner leads that are all connected together and would normally go to ground.  The 5th lead is the switch contact.

All of the 4-lead tact switches that I have seen have two pins on one end for one contact and two more pins on the other end as the other switch contact.

A couple of minutes with a multimeter (or battery/ resistor / LED) will tell you what is going fairly quickly.

If if does turn out like I described, it's easy to use the 4-lead switch instead of the 5-lead one.  Just put a layer of heat-resistant tape over top of the two pads on the PCB that correspond to the leads for one contact on the switch.  Solder a thin wire to those contacts on the switch, then mount the switch back to the PCB with the remaining two contacts.  Finally, the wire goes to the 5th contact on the PCB.

Easy!

Comment: The 4 pins tact switches are as you said,but i didn't understand your explanation about the 5 pins.Did you mean that the 4 pins at the corner are connected together as one contact(opposed to the 4 pins switch)and while i press the switch there is continuity to the fifth pin?